# VueJS/nuxt 'state' should be a method that returns an object in store/store.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm new to VueJS and confused about the warning from nuxt:

> 'state' should be a method that returns an object in store/store.js

So, my store.js contains the following (yes im trying the tutorial from the documentation):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';


Vue.use(Vuex);
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state() {
    return {
      todos: [
        { id: 1, text: '...', done: true },
        { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
      ]
    };
  }
});

export default store;
```

Isn't state a method which returns an object? Or did i misunderstood the message?

update:

I also tried the following:

```
state: () => ({
    todos: [
      { id: 1, text: '...', done: true },
      { id: 2, text: '...', done: false }
    ]
}),
```

But this will give me the same warning.

[image: VueJS/nuxt 'state' should be a method that returns an object in store/store.js]

Comment: Not sure which tutorial you're following but your store code seems significantly different from what's described in the Nuxt documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using Nuxt they expect a `store/index.js` to create a store and the format should be like:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  counter: 0
})

export const mutations = {
  increment (state) {
    state.counter++
  }
}
```

As you are creating a `store/store.js` file, that will be treated as a module and might not work as you expect. I strongly recommend to create a `store/index.js` and follow the docs from [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#activate-the-store).

Comment: ah, ok, now its working without warnings. thank you for the hint

Comment: I don't follow, what do I put in `./store/index.js`?

Comment: You should put the code above in `./store/index.js`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

**Use export const store**

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import user from './modules/user'

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user
  }
})
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing and I still get this error.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make a store/index.js then simply replace the state with this syntax, it will remove your warning. It worked for me as well.

```
export const state = () => ({
  cart: {
    booking: null,
    reservations: [],
  },
});
```